# Recursive functions in Matlab returns only first iteration result

Tags: matlab, recursion

I'm trying to make a recursive function in Matlab that constrains an angle to be returned between -180:180 degrees. So if i input an angle of 721 degrees, it should return 1 degree (two full revolutions and then 1).
Somehow, it's only returning the value after fist iteration.  I can see from the command window that it does the calculations correctly and inputs the updated values into the function. It ends up returning the wrong value.

1st: 721 - 360 = 361
2nd: 361 - 360 = 1

It returns 361 instead of 1 and it's driving be bonkers! :)

I've searched around, at it seems that newer versions might have an issue with recursive functions?

Here is my Matlab function:

```
function [constrainedTo180] = constrainingTo180(inputVector)
% Returns numbers to be constrained within +/- 180 degrees
% So 358 degrees is returned as -2 degrees
% fprintf('Running constraining function \n')

[ir,ic,ip] = size(inputVector);
constrainedTo180 = nan(ir,ic,ip);

for r = 1:ir % Iterate over rows
    for c = 1:ic  % Iterate over coloums
        for p = 1:ip  % Iterate over pages

            if inputVector(r,c,p) > 180
                constrainedTo180(r,c,p) = inputVector(r,c,p) - 360;
                fprintf('%d is Over 180 \nResult: %d \n\n\n',inputVector(r,c,p),constrainedTo180(r,c,p))
            elseif inputVector(r,c,p) < -180
                constrainedTo180(r,c,p) = inputVector(r,c,p) + 360;
                fprintf('Under -180 \n')
            else
                constrainedTo180(r,c,p) = inputVector(r,c,p);
                fprintf('else...\n')
            end
        end
    end

end

% Repeat until no values is outside [-180;180]
if max(abs(constrainedTo180(:))) > 180
    pause(1)
    fprintf('Max is %2.2f\n', max(abs(constrainedTo180(:))))
    inputVectorTemp = constrainedTo180;
    fprintf('Input to recursive function is %d \n', inputVectorTemp)
    constrainingTo180(inputVectorTemp);
end
```

If you simply run with a 1x1 matrix *constrainingTo180([721])* the command window outputs:

```
    721 is Over 180 
Result: 361 


Max is 361.00
Input to recursive function is 361 
361 is Over 180 
Result: 1 



ans =

   361
```

Let me know if I left any important information out. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are never assigning the new call of your recursive function to the original output.

Second to last line should be

```
constrainedTo180=constrainingTo180(inputVectorTemp);
```

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks a lot Noel. I really appreciate it!

Comment: Glad I could help. Please set your question as answered so it can be closed